# augmenting/index priority_queue in STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am using STL priority_queue as an data structure in my graph application. You can safely assume it like a  advance version of Prim's spanning tree algorithm. 
With in the Algorithm I want to find a node in the priority queue (not just a minimum node) efficiently.[ this is needed because cost of node might get changed and need to be fixed in priority_queue] 
All i have to do is augment the priority_queue and index it based on my node key's also. I don't find any way this can be done in STL. Can anyone have better idea how to do it in STL?

Comment: You could use a `std::map` instead... slower and more memory fragmentation/usage though. I don't think you can do what you want with a `priority_queue`.

Comment: @Dave Map is not a solution, i need to find the minimum key node all the time. Map does not do that.

Comment: Does too: `myMap.begin()` is just such a node.

Comment: @Igor no it is not. i need to: 1) Find the min weighted node (usually done through priority queue) 2) find location in data structure of the node usually done through Map.

Comment: You're using "minimum key" and "minimum weight" synonymously, but you don't seem to like the idea of using the weight as the key. Is there some misunderstanding here?

Comment: If weight is the key, then `myMap.begin()` points to the node with the smallest weight. If weight is not the key, then how exactly does priority queue help?

Comment: @Igor, Using Map does not solve the problem. its just shifts it. Imagine you have a map which is storing some GNode* as value and key is  a weight associated with the GNode*. Now if i ask you to find me a "Particular" GNode* because i want to update it/delete it. Will it not talk linear time and we have to traverse the whole map?

Comment: @Beta, i Got the point of using the minimum weight as the key. But it does not solve the purpose. See my response to Igor above

Comment: I see. You are looking for something like [boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: No. He is looking for [Boost Fibonacci-heap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html).

Comment: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html. It's in Java, but you can rewrite in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::priority_queue<T>` doesn't support efficient look-up of nodes: it uses a [d-ary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap), typically with `d == 2`. This representation doesn't keep nodes put. If you really want to use a `std::priority_queue<T>` with Prim's algorithm, the only way is to just add nodes with their current shortest distance and possibly add each node multiple times. This turns the size of the into `O(E)` instead of `O(N)`, though, i.e., for graphs with many edges it will result in a much higher complexity.

You can use something like `std::map<...>` but that really suffers from pretty much the same problem: you can either locate the next node to extract efficiently or you can locate the nodes to update efficiently.

The "proper" approach is to use a node-based priority queue, e.g., a [Fibanocci-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap): Since the nodes stay put, you can get a handle from the heap when inserting a node and efficiently update the distance of a node through the handle. Access to the closest node is efficient using the few top nodes in the heap's set of trees. The overall performance of basic heap operations (`push()`, `top()`, and `pop()`) are slower for Fibonacci heaps than for d-ary heaps but the efficient update of individual nodes makes their use worthwhile. I seem to recall that Prim's algorithm actually required Fibonacci-heaps anyway to achieve the tight complexity bound.

I know that there is an implementation of Fibonacci-heaps at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). An efficient implementation of Fibonacci heaps isn't entirely trivial but they are more efficient than just being of theoretical interest.

Comment: In such situation do you resort to you own implementation of priority_queue, i can imagine to write a priority queue implementation with a indexing/lookup capability.

Comment: Also did you find any implementation of union find in STL. i find one in boost disjoint_sets but not in STL. that way STL looks to me very limited in capability for implementing advanced graph algorithms

Comment: We are not using BOOST in our projects, so it is significant effort  to modify the make files to support the linking to boost. (And i am not in a position to decide the use of BOOST)

Comment: @David: In the long distant past I had helped to start Boost by submitting three packages. I didn't pursue any of them but functionality from all three is now either in Boost or in the standard or about to get into the standard. One of the packages was a "heap of heaps" which included a Fibonacci heap. The is probably floating about on the Internet but I don't know where: I would implement a Fibonacci heap but it is somewhat non-trivial. An easier alternative may be a d-ary heap which tracks were nodes currently are.

Comment: @David: with respect to support for graph algorithms, the standard C++ library doesn't have to anything, really. It doesn't seem to be much interest for graph algorithms in the C++ community or people are happy to use the Boost Graph Library (which is good; I'm biased though: in my diploma thesis I described the same concepts just a couple of years earlier). Union-Find is an interesting data structure which is best implemented as a special property map (see BGL for an explanation of property maps). I can imagine that BGL actually has such a property map.

Comment: Thanks you!! All of your comments are really helpful. and Finally thanks for the nice answer.